# GDAL python rotate TRMM data

Tags: gdal, rotate

I'm new to GDAL python API, when I tried to rotate a TRMM image, I got a weird result compared to the output of ENVI. I just want to rotate the image with 270 degrees, the result is also flipped vertically.

the output of ENVI desktop
[image]

the result with using gdal
[image]

```
import math
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
from osgeo import osr

# open the file
precip = gdal.Open('HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"/home/wanghl/wxq/3B43.19980101.7.HDF":0')

# get the data of the precipitation dataset
preciparr = precip.ReadAsArray()

# get geotransform
transform = precip.GetGeoTransform()

#rotate

rotation = (math.pi/180) * 270


# set geotif driver
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

# get x,y dimensions of the map
xs = precip.RasterXSize
ys = precip.RasterYSize

new_geotransform = (transform[0],
                    transform[1],
                    -math.sin(rotation) * transform[1],
                    transform[3],
                    math.sin(rotation) * transform[5],
                    transform[5])
# set output name
outname = "/home/wanghl/wxq/3B43.19980101.7.tif"

# set projection
target = osr.SpatialReference()

# write dataset to disk
outputDataset = driver.Create(outname, xs, ys, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
outputDataset.SetGeoTransform(new_geotransform)
outputDataset.SetProjection(target.ExportToWkt())
outputDataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(preciparr)
outputDataset.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-9999)
outputDataset = None
```